# Enter Developer Options when there is a password to protect us doing it

Tags: android

I bought an Android Device, it is running Android 4.4. The manufacture put a password to keep other accessing Developer Options, which is what I need because I need to enable "USB Debugging Mode" in "Developer Options".

Any suggestion to resolve this problem?

Comment: Contact manufacturer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic it should be asked to some customer support, not us.